# Customizing row 0 of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to insert some UILabels into the first row of a UITableView, but I'm getting unexpected results. For sake of brevity, here's a summary:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString* identifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc[ .....

cell.textLabel.text = @"";

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.backgroundColor = ....
    UILabel* x = .....
    [x setTag:1];
    [cell insertSubview:x];
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = ....
    for (UIView* view in cell.subviews) {
        if (view.tag == 1)
            [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

return cell
```

}

That's the gist anyway. The problem is that while the background color is being set correctly, anytime I scroll the table view, the custom UILabel I insert disappears. Maybe this stems from a misunderstanding of  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but regardless, I would think that the label would be reinserted.

Comment: While setting the cell’s background color in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` works most of the time, the *official* way to do it is in [`-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: `insertSubview`? it may only be an example of your code but it helps to be accurate. Just copy and paste your real code and then we can see exactly what is going on. You should also be adding views to the cell's `contentView` not straight to cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use different cell identifiers, and do the full initializing of the cell when it's created, instead of creating, adding and removing a lot of views each time a cell is requested.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString* normalCellIdentifier = @"Normal Cell";
  static NSString* specialCellIdentifier = @"Special Cell";

  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:specialCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc[ .....
      cell.backgroundColor = ....
      UILabel* x = .....
      [cell insertSubview:x];
    }

    return cell
  } else {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:normalCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc[ .....
    cell.textLabel.text = ....
    return cell;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add something simple such as a label you don't need different cell classes.

Try this:

```
/* ARC code */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (0 == indexPath.row) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Zero";
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={80, 20}}];
        lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lbl.text = @"@@@@";
        [cell addSubview:lbl];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Not zero";
    }    
    return cell;
}
```

Then, read elsewhere about `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Also, for similar cases you have `- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag`
 in `UIView` and its subclasses, no need to implement yours.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to try and minimize instantiation of views to a minimum to reduce work for the system.

@EmilioPelaez has one solution but the only gripe I have is that the code is pretty ugly with the repetition and multiple exits.

I would be much happier doing it like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    const NSInteger tag = 1;

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 
                                       reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier] autorelease];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
        label.hidden = YES;
        label.tag = tag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release]; label = nil;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    UILabel *label = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:tag];

    if (0 == indexPath.row) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        label.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Some text";
        label.hidden = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Think of it like the bits between the `if (!cell) { ... }` is where you do the heavy lifting and set up the tableview cell in a general form.

Then after that you are just configuring the view components.

If the cells vary too much then I would probably consider going with different reuse identifiers and possibly use a subclass of `UITableViewCell` or a `xib`